# How to call third party post api in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, api

`

```
String url = "http://be18-2401-4900-1c72-d22f-31a3-54-23e-d866.ngrok.io/ocr-client/upload";

        HttpResponse<String> res = null;

        // http request
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(URI.create(url)).header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .POST(BodyPublishers.ofFile(Paths.get("D:\\files\\testdata\\mrz_passport_2.jpg"))).build();

        HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder().build();

        res = client.send(request, BodyHandlers.ofString());

        System.out.println(res.statusCode());
        System.out.println(res.body())
```

`

There are many code and tutorials on internet calling third party api in spring boot but they are using Get method but in my case, I want to send a file in form-data...please help me how to call api with post request

Comment: so use tutorial of sending form data

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-multipart-upload#:~:text=Uploading%20a%20Single%20File&text=Set%20the%20content-type%20header,data%20along%20with%20some%20metadata.&text=Next%2C%20build%20the%20request%20body%20as%20an%20instance%20of%20LinkedMultiValueMap%20class.